# Using a self generated key to test java ssl app

Tags: java, netbeans, ssl

i'm working on a very simple server that uses ssl (in netbeans) - to test it i've created a certificate following the instructions here: 
http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbxw.html

```
java-home\bin\keytool -genkey -alias server-alias-keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks

java-home\bin\keytool -export -alias server-alias -storepass changeit -file server.cer -keystore keystore.jks

java-home\bin\keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-alias -file server.cer -keystore cacerts.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit
```

Now to get a simple echo server using ssl going, i'vre tried a variety of code: all of which throw lots of exceptions - one example is below:

```
try {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "cacerts.jks");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");

            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

            ServerSocket ss = ssf.createServerSocket(5432);
        } catch (Exception e {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is this the best way to be doing this?

The java page mentions this:

> You must enter the server name in
>   response to keytool’s first prompt, in
>   which it asks for first and last
>   names. For testing purposes, this can
>   be localhost.
>
> When you run the example applications,
>   the host specified in the keystore
>   must match the host identified in the
>   javaee.server.name property specified
>   in the file
>   tut-install/javaeetutorial5/examples/bp-project/build.properties.

How do i apply this to code im building (and running) in the netbeans ide?

**UPDATE: it throws the following errors**

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.throwException(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:142)
        at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:149)
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:23)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1245)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:220)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:147)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:125)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:68)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLServerSocketFactory.java:96)
        at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:21)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cacerts.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.getDefaultKeyManager(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:120)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl.<init>(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cacerts.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl$2.run(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:123)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl$2.run(DefaultSSLContextImpl.java:121)
        ... 16 more
```

many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you used 'localhost' as the hostname in the self-signed certificate, then HTTPS will only work when you send requests to your server using 'localhost' as the domain name for the request.

**EDIT** : based on the exception, I'd say that the real problem may be that your keystore file is not in the location that the JVM expects it to be.  Try using an absolute pathname in the system property that gives the location.

Comment: thats fine - the project is only meant to run locally for the moment, but i cant even seem to get it to work on localhost... (ie. running the server and client both on the same computer)

Comment: @oneADay - Are you using the machine's DNS name or "localhost" in the request URLs?  If you are doing the former, then a cert for "localhost" will not work.  I would suggest you create and configure a self-signed cert for the machine's DNS name as well.

Comment: I ran into the same error when giving the path to the keystore using a tilde (~/keystore.p12). When I switched to the full path name (/home/user/keystore.p12) it worked fine.

Comment: @CoverosGene - Java doesn't do tilde expansion when opening files.  It passes the pathname to the OS ... and that does expande tildes either.  Tilde expansion a >>shell<< functionality.