# Java and SSL - java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, security, ssl

I've built a Java program as a front end for a database on a server, and I'm trying to use SSL to encrypt traffic between clients and the server.  Here is the command I issued to create the server certificate:

```
keytool -genkey -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keypass kpass123 -storepass kpass123 -keystore keystore.jks
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
                   "G:/Data/Android_Project/keystore.jks");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyPassword", "kpass123");

SSLServerSocketFactory factory = 
    (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

SSLServerSocket accessSocket = 
    (SSLServerSocket)factory.createServerSocket(DB_ACCESS_PORT);
```

When I try to run this, I catch this:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)

I've also found that the "KeyPairGenerator" service has algorithms DIFFIEHELLMAN, DSA, RSA available to it, while "SSLContext" has algorithms SSL, TLS, SSLV3, DEFAULT, TLSV1.

Do I need to find some way to install RSA into the SSLContext service?  Am I even looking at the correct services?  Should I not be using RSA?

I'm new to the whole SSL - Security - Certificates thing, and it just blows me away that each of these different services don't have the same algorithms when they are supposed to be accessing the same certificates.

Comment: Looks eerily similar to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125686/using-a-self-generated-key-to-test-java-ssl-app). I suspected the limited cryptography support first, but 1024-bit strong keypairs should have worked fine. RSA should be available without adding any separate providers.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I looked at that question, and it appears I am doing everything correctly but still getting exceptions.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see the various "Caused by" exceptions you get before this `NoSuchAlgorithmException`: that's often where the real cause lies.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` instead of `javax.net.ssl.keyPassword`: the latter isn't mentioned in the [JSSE ref guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).

The algorithms you mention should be there by default using the default security providers. `NoSuchAlgorithmException`s are often cause by other underlying exceptions (file not found, wrong password, wrong keystore type, ...). It's useful to look at the full stack trace.

You could also use `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`, or at least `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,keymanager`, to get more debugging information, if the information in the stack trace isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Bruno Yes the whole "keystore pass must be same as keypass" and also I had the old password on the "keyStorePassword" line but your answer reminded me to check that again. THANKS a lot!

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  Turns out I needed single quotes around the two Java system properties for the keystore in the systemd start file /etc/systemd/system/activemq.service - otherwise the password property is skipped due to the space as per: https://askubuntu.com/questions/614106/how-to-specify-an-environment-systemd-directive-containing - e.g. Environment='ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/activemq/conf/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secret'