# JRE 1.8 compatibility

Tags: java

I have a Java application (run via batch file). The application connects to a server for which we use certificates.

There has been a change in the server certificate now and we imported the same into the Java keystore.

Now after this change, the application works fine when we use JRE1.7 to run it, but with JRE 1.8 we get the below exception. Can someone help.

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
```

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: can you show full error stack?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmVma.jpg

Comment: i'm not sure, but may you forgot a field in the certificate? whats that "enter image description here"? Maybe java is a bit too clearly there :|

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365209/java-and-ssl-java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception

Comment: @moneydhaze That was an incorrect msg displayed when I tried to insert an image, not a part of the exception trace.

Comment: @user7294900 Thanks let me check

Comment: Maybe update the title to reflect the problem more clearly: "JRE 1.8 PublicKey algorithm not implemented: ECPublicKey".

Answer (score -1):

From the full stacktrace in the PasteBin link, this is the root cause:

`Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: PublicKey algorithm not implemented: ECPublicKey
    at iaik.x509.X509Certificate.c(Unknown Source) ~[iaik_jce_full-3.18.1.jar:3.181]
    at iaik.x509.X509Certificate.decode(Unknown Source) ~[iaik_jce_full-3.18.1.jar:3.181]
    at iaik.x509.X509Certificate.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[iaik_jce_full-3.18.1.jar:3.181]
    at iaik.x509.CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[iaik_jce_full-3.18.1.jar:3.181]
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getTrustManagers(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 22 common frames omitted`

Can you paste the code that is used to create the Cipher? I think you might need to change it to use SunJCE.

Something like this:

`Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding","SunJCE");`

I can only say for certain when I see how you are initializing things.

Comment: I cannot add the full stacktrace as it says word limit exceeded. Any option to attach as file?

Comment: If you are still having trouble, maybe paste the full stacktrace into PasteBin and send the link.

Comment: I did not set that property anywhere.

Comment: You are right, that was just a guess. It looks like the root cause of the stacktrace is another Exception, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding","IAIK");   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF8"));
return HexBin.bytesToString(ciphertext);

Comment: This is the encrypt code and we have one for the decrypt function.

Comment: Try changing the Provider to "SunJCE". It might be that IAIK doesn't work with Java 8. ```Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding","SunJCE")```

Comment: It could also be that you need to upgrade your version of iaik_jce_full. It looks like you have an old version. Looking at their website, version 5.0 is the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 options, let me try them.