# Tomcat SSL certificates -- Post request Fails

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate, keystore

I have a Tomcat Java app that is trying to make the following request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?scope=profile+email
```

I see when it attempts to write to the connection that it fails.

```
conn.getOutputStream().write(content);
```

where the content being written to the body was the data shown above.  It throws the following error:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
```

When I hook up Fiddler to Tomcat, I can see the request just prior to that was successfull sent: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
But I never actually see in Fiddler the next request being sent that fails to the URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token

based on this and the message that it prints, it seems like it fails when preparing the data to send.

The problem sounds like something with SSL and certificates.
I downloaded the two certificates for the URL https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token and installed them into first Tomcat's keystore and then the truststore.  (First added it to the keystore and when that didn't work, I added to the trustsstore.
That didn't fix the problem.

Since I log the data that's being written to the output stream, I tried to manually copying the request body data from the log file including the code returned from Google and pasting it into a the Chrome extension "Rest Console".
When I do that it works.  But I see that Chrome already has a certificate installed for https://www.googleapis.com, so maybe that is the reason why the request from the browser worked.

In the oAuth1 version of this code, I don't think that we needed to install certificates.  Also, when I run the Java example from the Google oAuth2, unless the certificates are somehow packaged with Jetty, I don't see that they are installed.  So, I am not positive that certificates are the problem.

In Tomcat, I tried to turn on debugging for SSL by adding the following to the Tomcat JVM startup:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,session,defaultctx,trustmanager,keymanager
```

That writes lots of information, but there was nothing being written just prior to the error occurring.

How can I determine what is wrong?

=================================

Here is the stack trace:

```
  2018-03-19 08:32:11,324  DEBUG [scribe.model.Request] [http-bio-8080-exec-11] 
  java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation 
  (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: 
  sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
   2018-03-19 08:32:11,324  DEBUG [scribe.model.Request] [http-bio-8080-exec-11] 
  java.lang.Throwable:
        at org.scribe.model.Request.addBody(Request.java:153)
        at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:113)
        at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:69)
        at org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:12)
        at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth20ServiceImpl.java:38)
        at ch.gadp.alfresco.OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.getUserProfile(OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:192)
        at ch.gadp.alfresco.OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.processRequestToken(OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:331)
        at ch.gadp.alfresco.OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.doOAuthAuthentication(OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:375)
        at ch.gadp.alfresco.OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: maybe duplicate, see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365209/java-and-ssl-java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception

Comment: The other article suggests turning on ssl debug and double checking the stack trace.  I will the stacktrace, but don't see any clues there.

Comment: it says there was a typo (keystorepassword / keypassword)

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like a (server) cert problem, but the only throws for that exception in java.security.Provider always set a cause that should be displayed in the stacktrace as a section beginning 'Caused by:' -- don't you have that?

Comment: No.  There is no "caused by".  The error was being ignored and nothing was showing up in the log, so there is a try/catch around the conn.getOutputStream().write(content) that writes the stacktrace when the error occurs.