# Unable to execute HTTP request: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am uploading image on AWS from my android app. In this attempt sometime I get the success and sometime I get failure and error as below:

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: AndroidOpenSSL, class: com.android.org.conscrypt.DefaultSSLContextImpl)

Please provide me solution for this as I can't get the exact reason about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365209/java-and-ssl-java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception

Comment: I checked, both are different. I am uploading image from Android Application.

Comment: Are you sure that the request is http and not https ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have created a bucket on s3, integrated aws sdk in android app and trying to upload image. Sometimes I got success but sometime I got this error. I am not sure why sometime.

Comment: Do you use any network with security and firewall sometimes  ?

Comment: I am using wifi and mobile network. But if the reason is this then how get success sometime.

Comment: For example you could use a corporate network, maybe in successfully uploads you switch to mobile network or in some cases the corporate network allow to upload the picture ! I have seen it in my company !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200637/discussion-between-anurag-srivastava-and-vasilisfoo).

Comment: What is Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: AndroidOpenSSL, class: com.android.org.conscrypt.DefaultSSLContextImpl). I am getting this error for everything.